# Spring Social, JCR and Magnolia

Tags: spring, spring-social, jcr, magnolia

I have a problem on setting up spring social as a module for Magnolia CMS.
What i want to do is, implementing the Connect Controller and so on to make me an oauth and then go over to my adapted register or login form, so i don't really need that many stuff.
Spring Social is JDBC based. I don't really know on how to access the given magnolia jcr template and connect to my users workbench to make something equal to what is done in the so many given samples.
I am inside the jcr vm, so i normally should have access to all things, the other classes have too. I also have nice things like MgnlContext to fetch it, but that all doesn't help me.
There's no adequate reaction on spring social forum or magnolia forum, what i really can't understand ...
Is there somebody out there, who can help me with that ?
It's just making the bridge, what i am asking for, i don't need anything else, no viewtemplate or so on, it would be enough to make something like /signin/facebook or twitter or so.

How would i access JCR Datasource and bind it to Spring Social ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MgnlContext and Spring Context are two separate objects, you can't obtain one from the other.
If you want to use Spring Social from the templates/webpages you show to your users, that should be quite simple, just make sure you have SS installed (follow same setup as shown in their samples) and add same markup to the template. You would need however to create a bypass in Magnolia filter chain for the path on which you will have social installed, or added all necessary filters & servlets to Magnolia's filter chain directly. More details about filter chain and bypass config at http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Request+processing+and+filters

To make it even easier, you might want to install Magnolia Blossom Model that let you configure views from examples on SS directly as templates in Magnolia. For more details on Blossom look at http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module